# Laravel Component Controller Params Does not Pass to Blade Files

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to pass a public var to blade files but I want to process it under Component Controller.

Component Usage

```
<x-membership.my-membership></x-membership.my-membership>
```

Component controller

```
class MyMembership extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public function __construct(
        public $userMembership,
        public $showExpired = null,
    )
    {
        $this->userMembership = Auth::user()->user_membership;
        Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
        if($this->userMembership){
            $this->showExpired = Carbon::parse($this->userMembership->expired_at)->translatedFormat('j F Y');
        }
        else{
            $this->showExpired = null;
        }

        // When it is null then display regular membership
        if(!$this->userMembership){
            $this->userMembership = new Membership();
            $this->userMembership->membership = Membership::where('price',0)->first();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.membership.my-membership');
    }
}
```

Here is the blade files

```
@isset($user_membership)
    <div id="myMembership">
        <div
            class=" text-gray-900 bg-white border border-gray-200 rounded-lg dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:text-white">
            <div class="p-2 border-b flex justify-between capitalize">
                <span>{{ __('Membership') }}</span>
                <span>{{ $user_membership->membership->name }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 {{ $show_expired ? 'border-b' : '' }} flex justify-between capitalize">
                <span>{{ __('Max Slot') }}</span>
                <span>{{ $user_membership->membership->max_slot }}</span>
            </div>
            @if ($show_expired)
                <div class="p-2 flex justify-between capitalize">
                    <span>{{ __('Expired At') }}</span>
                    <div>
                        <span>{{ $show_expired }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
@endisset
```

The main problem that $user_membership does not pass to blade file. It works under localhost but not working while in production.

This component is used by 3 views that is why I cannot pass directly to the usage for example like this

```
<x-membership.my-membership :membership="$user_membership"></x-membership.my-membership>
```

Using this one is working fine but I need to state on every controller to retrieve current membership while I just want to read it from Component Controller.

Edit: I tried to remove Component Controller from the production server to test out and it still can be opened without any problem. However in localhost it returns

```
Class "App\View\Components\Membership\MyMembership" not found
```

but why in production seems that laravel skip Controller Component, it just pass to the blade file which is similar to view. I also have done

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my perspective, we cannot use Component where we do not define any var. For example, I am using this one

```
<x-membership.my-membership></x-membership.my-membership>
```

Then after I change it into something like this

```
<x-membership.my-membership :user-membership="Auth::user()->user_membership"></x-membership.my-membership>
```

I know that, stating

```
:user-membership="Auth::user()->user_membership"
```

does not make any change because the result would be null. However, seems that __construct is working if we state a param there.